# Landscape mode app with fixed custom navigation menu on right side

Tags: ios

I have used container containment view in my project. My question is how can I set specific width for my child view controller's view that I need to show on click of my custom navigation menu button.
Currently I am setting view's width in viewdidload methods but on simulator it is not respecting my frame. My view gets cut on screen from right side.

[image]

Comment: put your code set frame.

Comment: I just used.. [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenHeight,screenWidth)]; in view did load. As screenWidth is height and screenHeight is width in landscape mode I set it accordingly.